# How do I install the current version of the `linux-headers-generic` package?

Tags: apt, 17.10

I am trying to install `virtualbox` which requires a kernel module to be compiled. This gives me an error saying :

```
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
    linux-headers-generic linux-headers-4.13.0-31-generic
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
    linux-headers-generic linux-headers-4.13.0-31-generic
```

Its figuring out the version of `linux-headers` required from `uname -r` which returns `4.13.0-31-generic`. However that version of the kernel headers has no installation candidate.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-4.13.0-31-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'linux-headers-4.13.0-31-generic' has no installation candidate
```

`dpkg-query` shows the old version is installed:

```
 sudo dpkg-query -l "linux-headers*"
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                           Version                      Architecture                 Description
+++-==============================================-============================-============================-==================================================================================================
un  linux-headers                                  <none>                       <none>                       (no description available)
un  linux-headers-2.6-686                          <none>                       <none>                       (no description available)
un  linux-headers-2.6-amd64                        <none>                       <none>                       (no description available)
un  linux-headers-3.0                              <none>                       <none>                       (no description available)
ii  linux-headers-4.13.0-16                        4.13.0-16.19                 all                          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.13.0
ii  linux-headers-4.13.0-16-generic                4.13.0-16.19                 amd64                        Linux kernel headers for version 4.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
un  linux-headers-4.13.0-21-generic                <none>                       <none>                       (no description available)
un  linux-headers-4.13.0-25-generic                <none>                       <none>                       (no description available)
un  linux-headers-4.13.0-31-generic                <none>                       <none>                       (no description available)
un  linux-headers-686-pae                          <none>                       <none>                       (no description available)
un  linux-headers-amd64                            <none>                       <none>                       (no description available)
ii  linux-headers-generic                          4.13.0.16.17                 amd64                        Generic Linux kernel headers
un  linux-headers-generic-pae                      <none>                       <none>                       (no description available)
```

How do I install the `linux-headers-4.13.0-31-generic` package?

[EDIT] : 
Manually installing the package from https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/linux-headers-4.13.0-31 works!